# What is the appropriate sizing for fiberglass compatible with polyamide?

Tags: synthesis, polymers, materials

I am looking for a chemical coating for glass A fibers, compatible with polyamide. The fibers are uncoated, 100-filament strands of 22-micrometer "A" glass fibers.

We are producing fiberglass in our lab, and we want to size (coat) them with something which can keep the strands together and at the same time enables the fibers to bond with polyamide. We can use materials like PVA to keep the strands together, but then the fibers do not bond with the polyamide (mixing with polyamide happens after we produce the strands and chop them, with 4mm in length).

I am a beginner in composite world so I would appreciate if you can give me details on how and where to buy such chemical, or how to synthesis it myself if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think epoxy resin is compatible with polyamide because its chemical structure. Epoxy is compatible with silica (glass) and poyamide functional groups then it could be a good sizing .